# How to change stacking order of bg image?

Tags: html, css, background-image

How can I make it so that the mouth, eyes, and eyebrows appear on top of the face without changing the html? (The mouth is in the wrong position so I can see it)

```
    <body>

<div id = "shoulders">

    <div id = "face">
        <div class = "eyebrow" id = "lefteyebrow"> </div>

        <div class = "eyebrow" id = "righteyebrow"> </div>

        <div class = "eye" id = "lefteye"> </div>

        <div class = "eye" id = "righteye"> </div>

        <div id = "mouth"></div>

    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tvkhb8zt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways to achieve what you want.

1. As mentioned before you can use `z-index`. Just remember that if you have complicated structure of a page it is not recommended to use `z-index`.
2. Easier approach may be to use simple relative/absolute positioning. Here is a good [article](http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-positioning/) of explaining `CSS` positioning. This is [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6b7ytt4u/) example of your image with positioned mouth and head on top of shoulders.

Answer (score 0):

try css property: z-index

```
   <div class = "eyebrow" id = "lefteyebrow" style="z-index:0"> </div>

    <div class = "eyebrow" id = "righteyebrow" style="z-index:1"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add z-index to the CSS. Please note z-index only works on explicity positioned elements, so just add a position: relative as well. Largest z-index will be on top.

So for example:

```
#face, .eyebrow, .eye {
    position: relative;
}

#face {
    z-index: 1;
}

.eyebrow {
    z-index: 2;
}

.eye {
    z-index: 2;
}
```